# Install tire on wheel

Tags: tire, wheels, rims, installation

I bought a new wheel (Mach1 560, https://www.santafixie.com/en/mach1-560-rear-wheel-black.html) and a new tire (Michelin, 700cx35) without any default (no veiled).

The point is I have problem to put my tire: as you can see in this video, my wheel seems to be veiled (but is not), it is just that my tire is not correctly installed.

I tried several times to reinstalled the tire on the rim but same effect.

Do you have any advice on how to avoid such default ?

https://rpidejr.hopto.org/f/ee90ab99557c42eb9dc6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly (not sure what you mean by "veiled"), it is that the tire is not sitting uniformly on the wheel. This is a common problem, and it's easy to fix: over-inflate the tire by about 10% beyond the inflation limit shown on its sidewall. This will pop the bead into place on the rim. Then let out the excess pressure.

Comment: yep solved it thanks